# Why is chi squared for paired coin tosses so sensitive to slight deviations from 1:2:1?

Tags: p-value, chi-squared-test, combinatorics

I've been using googlesheets to calculate and understand how chi squares work in paired coin tosses as a model for pairing of alleles in Punnet squares.  I used the randbetween(0,1) function to simulate 1000 pairs of coin tosses, and then using the AND, XOR, and NOT(OR) operators, I was able to count the three following categories: 11, 10 + 01, and 00.  Then I explicitly calculated chi squared and subsequently used the chidist function to find the p value for 2 degrees of freedom, as would be done in genetics analyses.  I plotted the observed frequencies of all 3 categories and also the incremental chi square, increasing by units of 10 flips.  By using googlesheet's calculation refresh, I can visualize multiple traces of category frequency and chi square.

I'm surprised by the relatively large number of times that the chi square touches or dips below the 0.05 p value in the graph, particularly in the domain of higher numbers of flips, say greater than 800.  This dipping occurs perhaps once every 5-10 refreshes.  In research practice a p value of 0.05 or less leads to rejection of the null hypothesis, here that is the 50:50 probabilities model.  By eye the data seems to be converging but the instrument of chi square analysis misses this more times than I would have thought.  I had naively thought the "law of averages" driving convergence to near the 1:2:1 ratio would lead to p-values safely larger than 0.05.  If the convergence is very tight as sometimes happens, the p value is well above 0.05.

Moreover, at the beginning of the graph, with only a tens of flips, the convergence hasn't proceeded very much, but the p value remains quite large.

In the attached figure, AA represents 11, Aa and aA represents 10 and 01, and aa represents 00.  I'd really appreciate any comments/answers about why chi square is so sensitive to seemingly slight straying from 1:2:1 convergence for large numbers of flips.

I'd really appreciate any explanation about what is happening. Is this just a feature of chi square that would work itself out better after 10,000 paired flips?  Are these p value potholes always out there waiting for an unlucky researcher?

[image]

Comment: You are performing the kind of experiment described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310119.  These "p value potholes" await the researcher who abuses hypothesis testing in the manner related there.

Comment: @whuber Thanks that is really helpful